# EPSON PRINTER XP405WH

Tags: printing

I am trying to find a printer that will run with my Ubuntu 11.04 installation and, having just been to my local PCWorld store. *(Wonder if this Epson printer will run with Ubuntu)*

I already have a Lexmark 1480 printer but there is no Ubuntu compatible for this printer so I need another one.

Answer (score 0):

HP probably has the best Ubuntu (in fact, Linux) support amongst all of the manufacturers. have a look at http://h10018.www1.hp.com/wwsolutions/linux/products/printing_imaging/

You should not need to install any drivers - just connect the HP printer over USB and let Ubuntu do its thing.